# Testing simple Android chat messenger

Tags: android, windows, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I'm developing a simple chat messenger in android for my assignment. I need to run 2 AVD emulators to test my app. But it seems Android doesn't provide enough flexibility for network environment for AVDs. Could you please help me out how to run 2 AVDs to test my messenger app in Windows ? I'm using Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running two instances of eclipse? One for each phone emulation. I've done this to test client/server programs that use my local machine as the host.

Comment: It seems windows has some issues in supporting multiple AVD instances run at the same time. So our prof asked to switch to Mac or linux. Thanks for your answer and sorry for the late comment.